# Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations

Tags: r, dplyr, forecasting

When I do forecast using `forecast` library, I noticed following code does not run as expected:

```
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(gp=gl(20,5), dt=seq(1:100))

get <- function (df1){
  ts1 <- ts((df1%>%filter(gp==2))$dt)
  as.numeric(forecast(ar(ts1),15)$mean)
}    

print(get(df1))
```

The error return is:

> Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations

May be it is caused by `ar` or `ar.burg` function. Because if you change the function to `ets` or something else the function works well.

What is more strange is that if you change the code to:

```
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(gp=gl(20,5), dt=seq(1:100))
ts1 <- ts((df1%>%filter(gp==2))$dt)

get <- function (ts1){
  as.numeric(forecast(ar(ts1),15)$mean)
}


print(get(ts1))
```

The code is also running correctly. I think this may be a bug in `ar` function, and the problem is somehow related to scope. Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is to do with scoping. `forecast()` tries to find the time series used to fit the model. The functions from the forecast package (such as `ets`) store this information in the model object, so it is easy for `forecast()` to find it. But `ar()` is from the stats package, and it does not store the time series used to fit the model. So `forecast()` goes looking for it. If you run your code outside of the `get()` function, it works ok because `forecast()` manages to find the `ts1` object in the local environment. But within the `get()` function it causes an error.

One simple fix is to add the information to the fitted model before calling `forecast`:

```
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(gp=gl(20,5), dt=seq(1:100))
ts1 <- ts((df1%>%filter(gp==2))$dt)

get <- function (ts1){
  fit <- ar(ts1)
  fit$x <- ts1
  as.numeric(forecast(fit,15)$mean)
}

print(get(ts1))
```

Alternatively, use `predict` instead of `forecast`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(gp=gl(20,5), dt=seq(1:100))
ts1 <- ts((df1%>%filter(gp==2))$dt)

get <- function (ts1){
  fit <- ar(ts1)
  as.numeric(predict(fit,n.ahead=15)$pred)
}

print(get(ts1))
```