# Error in ts(data) : R scoping issue

Tags: r

I am running my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

require(gdata)
library('ggplot2')
library('forecast')
library('tseries')

df1 <- read.xls('us-gasprices.xls',header = TRUE)
new = df1$V2
data = tail(new,-1)
data = ts(data)

fit = auto.arima(data, seasonal=FALSE)

png(filename="residuals.png")
tsdisplay(residuals(fit), lag.max=40, main='(4,1,1) Model Residuals')
plot(m)
dev.off()
```

Output

```
Error in ts(data) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations
```

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432595/error-in-tsx-ts-object-must-have-one-or-more-observations)
I understand what Rob has explained that the problem is in scoping.
When I run my code from R terminal line by line then it works fine.
But when I run Rscript in Ubuntu terminal the above-mentioned problem occurs.
How to solve this?

Comment: (1) perhaps a path issue? are you certain that it is finding the file in the correct directory? (2) I recommend against using `data` as a variable name, errors on the `data` *function* are not always obvious to interpret. (3) why do you use `require` and `library` differently? I'd suggest never using `require` unless you don't mind if it fails to load and allow the script to continue.

Comment: @r2evans I have checked path,renamed data and use only library now.I have the same problem.

Comment: @MikiBelavista were you able to solve the problem? I am facing the same issue when I use the forecast package and use  y <- ts(Train$Amount, frequency=7) . I am running R script on my windows m/c and using tableau desktop on the same.  If anyone else has any idea of resolving this issue please let me know.